# Asp.net "Remember Me" does not work through FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage()

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, forms-authentication, remember-me

In my login page I'm using `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage()` to redirect to Home page after the user is validated. But it doesn't seem to obey `CreatePersistenceCookie` parameter. I have searched in Google and modified my Web.Config but still Remember Me functionality does not work.

this is my sample code structure (using asp.net login control as the login UI)

```
if (MyService.ValidateUser(LoginUser.UserName, LoginUser.Password))
{
   FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(LoginUser.UserName, LoginUser.RememberMeSet);
}
```

Web.Config

`<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx"
timeout="21600"
cookieless="AutoDetect"
name="MySiteAuth"
slidingExpiration="true"/>`

Even when LoginUser.RememberMeSet is True (user has selected Remember Me checkbox) the browser doesn't remember the session. So when I open the web site next time I'm presented with the Login page. Ideally Login page should only come if have specifically Logged-out in the previous session. otherwise it should persist my session.

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

thanks

Comment: And what about the timeout? Are you sure you're not reopening the browser after 6 hours have passed?

Comment: Of course. For testing this problem, I immediately reopened the browser and it still displayed the login screen. and FYI, "timeout" is taken in Minutes. so 21600 minutes is equal to 15 days.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link

["remember me" not working on login control](http://forums.asp.net/p/939811/1122878.aspx)

[Login control [remember me] cookie non-persistent](http://forums.asp.net/p/947381/1147268.aspx)

Comment: None of those seem to work. I referred to lot of articles like that. Seems like a popular issue. I decided to maintain my own cookie and it seems to work properly.